# PHP: Group words of a sentence into smaller groups with fixed number of words

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I have sentence like this:

```
I am in love with you
```

I want this to be in following combination for 3 words from left to right.

```
I am in
am in love
in love with
love with you
```

I tried the code below, but I think I'm complicating it...

```
$data = array_chunk(explode(" ", $sarr), 3);
$data = array_map(function($value) {
    return sprintf("<span>%s</span>", implode(" ", $value));
}, $data);
echo implode("\n", $data);
```

Any ideas on how to do it fast and efficiently? This must work for 5000 words.

Comment: You're pretty set there. "Split into words, chunk words into groups of 3, join each group back together"... I can't really see any better way of doing it.

Comment: But I get only two sets I am in & love with you

Comment: Oh I see, you want a kind of *rolling* 3-word grouping. OK, that's a little trickier, but what you can do is `explode` and then `map` each word to the `slice` starting at its index and pulling in the next 2 words. `slice` the last two entries off and there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Regular Expressions to work around this. You match one word then capture two other following words with a positive lookahead and stick them together within a `foreach` loop.

```
$words = [];
preg_match_all('~\b\w+(?=((?:\s+\w+){2}))~', $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $word) {
    // 1st iteration => $word = "I", $matches[1][0] = " am in"
    $words[] = $word . $matches[1][$key];
}
```

Outputs (`print_r($words);`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => I am in
    [1] => am in love
    [2] => in love with
    [3] => love with you
)
```

Output of `echo implode(PHP_EOL, $words);`:

```
I am in
am in love
in love with
love with you
```

Answer (score 1):

You were certainly off to a strong start, but you want a rolling window over your array. You can achieve this like so:

```
// split the string into words
$words = explode(" ", $sarr);
// for each index in the array, get that word and the two after it
$chunks = array_map(function($i) use ($words) {
    return implode(" ", array_slice($words,$i,3));
}, array_keys($words));
// cut off the last two (incomplete) chunks
$chunks = array_slice($chunks,0,-2);
// glue the result together
echo implode("\n",$chunks);
```

Comment: Interesting that regex solution is x10 times faster on `n ≃ 6500`.